# Hide non-standard python user input

Tags: python, input, terminal

I am creating a console game, which takes user key presses.

I had trouble with hiding the letters that then spread across the screen simply because the user is pressing a button.

It won't work with modules like `getpass`, and I have already tried various ANSI codes to attempt to hide the text. The background is also full of text characters and symbols, so that stops just a complete ANSI character disappearo. I also don't wanna have to call `os.system("clear")` every frame, because even calling it once every second bugs out the terminal.

What I want to know, is whether there is a way to catch key presses without having said key appear on the console

Here is the board class I am using, and the `draw()` method inside is how I have been drawing it to the terminal:

```py
class board:
  def __init__(self,length):
    import random
    self.random=random
    self.characters=[" ","░","▒","▓","█"]
    self.length=length
    self.dithering=False
    self.board=[[self.random.choice(self.characters) for y in range(self.length)] for x in range(self.length)]
  def draw(self,colour=None):
    if colour==None:
      colour=RGB(0,1,0)
    for x in range(len(self.board)):
      for y in range(len(self.board)):
        if self.board[y][x]==None:
          continue
        f=1
        if self.dithering==True:
          f=self.random.random()+0.5 # faintness
        print(f"\u001b[{y};{x*2+1}H\x1b[38;2;{int(colour.r*f)};{int(colour.g*f)};{int(colour.b*f)}m{str(self.board[y][x])*2}",end="")
    print("\x1b[0m")
  def redecorate(self,characters=None):
    if characters==None:
      characters=self.characters
    self.board=[[self.random.choice(characters) for y in range(self.length)] for x in range(self.length)]
  def empty(self):
    self.board=[[None for y in range(self.length)] for x in range(self.length)]

class RGB:
  def __init__(self,r,g,b):
    self.r=r*255
    self.g=g*255
    self.b=b*255
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to catch user's key presses without displaying them? Please make you question more understandable.

Comment: @UltraStudioLTD Sorry 'bout the confusion. Yes, I would like to catch the key presses without displaying them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To catch key presses without displaying them you need **getch** function. On **Windows** you can use **msvcrt** module to capture it, while on **Unix-like** and **Linux** platforms you need   to implement it by yourself, although it is easy.

Here is code for **Windows**:

```py
from msvcrt import getch
```

And for **Linux** and **Unix-like** platforms:

```py
import sys
import termios
import tty
def getch() -> str:
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    return ch
```

> **NOTE**: some keys are more than one char long (like arrow keys which are 3 char long) so you will need to run *getch* few times to fully capture it.

Comment: So, to get this straight, I need to run this function just before the program, and it will keep key press characters invisible for the whole program?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry for late reply, it was night. Answer is no. What this function does is that unlikely **input** or **sys.stdin.read*** that  when called it only gets one char from **sys.stdin** and returns it without displaying that char.